# Android - "Open with" dialog still displays even after choosing an option from Intent.createChooser

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an `Imageview` by clicking on which i need to open chooser which will show multiple apps which are eligible to open urls.I am doing something like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(article.getAndroidUrl()));
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>21){
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT);
                } else {
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
                }
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open Url Using"));
```

This works fine and open up the chooser. But among all the apps , if i choose "default browser" app of the device, then it again asks for "Open with" dialog. However if i choose other apps like chrome or firefox then it works fine and no 2nd open with dialog is shown.

So apart from default browser app, for other browser apps it works fine.

**Question: Is there any known issue as such that even after using `Intent.createChooser` , for default browser, another "open with" dialog will open to ask again which app to use? If yes how to get rid of that?**

Note: This doesn't happen in every device. For some devices this works fine but for other devices it asks for open with dialog again even after choosing an option from `Intent.createChooser`.

Comment: I'm guessing this is due to the default browser redirecting to the site's mobile page, which causes it to handle it like a new request, so it pops the chooser again. I've seen this before with the default browser on Samsungs, and YouTube URLs. It's not an issue with `Intent.createChooser()`, but just with how certain browsers behave.

Comment: Thanks for replying @MikeM So haven't you come across any solution to deal with this issue?

Comment: You could pass the mobile site URL explicitly, so it wouldn't have to redirect. That might not be desirable, though, or even possible, depending on your circumstance.

Comment: Exactly! It works if we pass directly the explicit mobile site. Could you post this as an answer so that i can accept and upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here seems to have been with the particular browsers themselves, not necessarily with your `Intent` chooser. When being redirected to the mobile site, basic browsers often will just handle this as a new request, and may show an `Intent` chooser of their own.

A workaround for this is to pass the mobile site URL explicitly, if possible, which would eliminate the need for the redirect, and open the site directly in the chosen browser.

Comment: Are you aware of any workaround which can let the programmer know if the device has such a default browser which creates new request for redirection? I think this is not possible, but still just want to make sure once.

Comment: Ooh, yeah, no, I can't think of any way that would be possible, apart from keeping your own list of devices/browsers that you determine just from testing, and checking against that at runtime. But that seems like _waaay_ more trouble than it's worth.